# "Last refresh" message after updatepanel

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I can't seem to exactly find what I need out there so I'll ask.

I have a page that will be auto updating every 5-10 minutes or so using an ASP:Updatepanel and timer_tick event. I'm simply looking for a message that has something like:

```
    Last refresh was at:
    <script>document.write(document.lastModified);</script>
```

Or something like that.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an ASP.NET server control (i.e. `Label`) that gets updated when the server does a page load, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    ...
    <asp:Label id="LabelLastUpdated" runat="server" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Do update of data here and set last updated label to current time
    LabelLastUpdated.Text = "Last refresh was at: " & DateTime.Now.ToString("F")
End Sub
```

Note: The `"F"` is the full date/time pattern (long time). Read [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

---

UPDATE:

To use this is a master page scenario, where any content page refresh causes the label to update, then try this:

Master page's markup:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        ... Existing content ...
        <asp:Label id="LabelLastUpdated" runat="server" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Master page's code-behind:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Do update of data here and set last updated label to current time
    LabelLastUpdated.Text = "Last refresh was at: " & DateTime.Now.ToString("F")
End Sub
```

---

For a master page scenario where you want the content page to tell the master page to update, then try this:

Master page's markup:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        ... Existing content ...
        <asp:Label id="LabelLastUpdated" runat="server" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Master page's code-behind:

```
Sub UpdateLastUpdatedLabel()
    ' A content page is telling the last updated label to be set 
    ' to the current time
    LabelLastUpdated.Text = "Last refresh was at: " & DateTime.Now.ToString("F")
End Sub
```

In content page's code-behind:

In `Page_Load` or any other event you wish to use as a trigger to update the master page's label, do this:

```
' Get a reference to the master page
Dim masterPage = DirectCast(Page.Master, YourMasterPageClassName)

' Now you can call the master page's UpdateLastUpdatedLabel method
' which will update the label's text to the current date/time
masterPage.UpdateLastUpdatedLabel()
```

Comment: I think it is not the things as he wants!

Comment: Pretty much what I'm looking for. I can find some way to get it working on my current page, but if I wanted to put in on, say the master page, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @bender54 - put the label in the master page markup and have the `Page_Load` of the master page update the label control. This will update the label if any of the content pages cause a post back. I have a separate example of using the label in the master page, along with a method that the content page calls to actually update the label. See updated answer.

Comment: @bender54 - feel free to up-vote this answer when you can. :-)

Comment: I was just about to come back and say thanks again for the master page update, it's beautiful. I would upvote..but I uh, don't have the rep. I'll remind myself to do so when I get up there.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code which will update on regular interval

In aspx page :

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
   <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Page not refreshed yet." id="LabelLastUpdated">
   </asp:Label>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in code behind file add following code :

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelLastUpdated.Text = "Last Modified at: " +DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```